# Task of the Driver on Mach Zehnder Modulator

Tags: microcontroller, rf, laser

What is the task of the Driver of the MZM modulator? I'm trying to get RF input for the MZM, does the driver convert optical input to RF?

[image: MZM MZ Driver Modulator]

We have a driver, what's the purpose of it? How can I design it on [PathWave ADS](https://www.keysight.com/us/en/products/software/pathwave-design-software/pathwave-advanced-design-system.html)?

Comment: What driver - links to schematics please.

Comment: For example here; [link](https://imgshare.io/image/GUx69) We have a driver, what's the purpose of it? How can i design it on ADS?

Comment: This stuff needs to be embedded into your question and also technical data sheets for the driver.

Comment: I'm asking how the design looks like i need to see some exampless to get the idea, the research papers just show the simulation results and informations

Comment: *the research papers just show the simulation results and informations* Explain how I can easily find some schematics but you cannot like: https://www.researchgate.net/figure/Output-current-flow-in-the-MZM-driver-a-CML-b-push-pull_fig2_309920537  and  https://www.semanticscholar.org/paper/90mW%2C-4.4Vp-p%2C-11.35Gb%2Fs-MZM-driver-enabling-for-Nguyen-Li/38c6e3a538b5383431c4b29b4e122ae071ec076e  and 
 https://www.researchgate.net/figure/Stacked-CMOS-push-pull-MZM-segment-driver_fig2_329510186

Comment: *does the driver convert optical input to RF?* Look at the picture you included, what text is shown at the input of the driver? Hint: the thick black curves are bondwires to make an **electrical** connection.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because lack of original research

Answer (score 2):

An MZM modulator requires fairly high voltage.  (Also search on EO, electro-optic modulator.  Also Lithium Niobate, the dielectric material typically used.)

Drivers for EO electro-optical materials usually employ an RF amplifier, followed by a tuned circuit (an impedance-match network, series-resonant Pi type,) designed for the drive frequency.   The tuned circuit acts as a step-up transformer, while being more efficient than an actual transformer.

Find the spec sheet for your MZM modulator.   What is the peak AC voltage allowed, and the recommended AC voltage?   (Usually EO devices need hundreds of volts, unless they're built from thin-films, as shown in your link.  Maybe your "driver" is simply an RF amp, providing hundreds of milliwatts, since the EO material is like a nonlinear and lossy capacitor.)